# Помогите создать словарь в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict

Я в питоне новичок, поэтому прошу вашей помощи.
У меня есть список, элементы в котором выглядят следующим образом

```
26810,"vasya.vasin@test.ru","[""First value"",""Second value""]","0","0","","",""
```

По сути в элементе есть список.
Я хочу из всех элементов этого списка создать словарь в формате:

```
{26810: ('vasya.vasin@test.ru','[First value, Second value]', '0', '0', '', '', '')
 26811: ('ivan.ivanov@test.ru','[First value, Second value]', '0', '0', '', '', '')}
```

Я смог сделать это для одного элемента из списка

```
First_dict = {}
First_dict[literal_eval(first_list[2])[0]] = literal_eval(first_list[2])[1:],
```

однако не могу понять как сделать это циклом. Уже думал собирать два отдельных листа с ключом, второй с остальными данными, но есть риск что получится каша.
Буду рад любой помощи!

Answer (score 1):

```
first_list = [[26810, 'vasya.vasin@test.ru', '[''First value, Second value'']', 
               '0', '0', '', '', ''],
              [26811, 'ivan.ivanov@test.ru', '[''First value, Second value'']', 
               '0', '0', '', '', '']
             ]
First_dict = {}
for i in range(len(first_list)):
    First_dict[first_list[i][0]] = first_list[i][1::]
print(First_dict)

>>>{26810: ['vasya.vasin@test.ru', '[First value, Second value]', '0', '0', '', 
            '', ''],
    26811: ['ivan.ivanov@test.ru', '[First value, Second value]', '0', '0', 
            '', '', '']
   }
```

Comment: в этом срезе first_list[i][1::] можно с одним двоеточием, а так все правильно, первое что приходит на ум)

Comment: В `import this` есть следующие: **Readability counts.** - читаемость имеет значение. После того, как я несколько раз ошибся и принял "укороченный" слайс за указатель, решил всегда писать слайс в полном виде [ : : ]. И вам советую. :-)

Comment: ясно, но по мне так одно двоеточие норм, я так и представляю врезы, шаги не всегда используются и в голове, когда они нужны, тогда и всплывает дополнительное двоеточие. Кто как привыкает)

Answer (score 1):

```
literal_eval = [[26810, ('vasya.vasin@test.ru','[First value, Second value]', '0', '0', '', '', '')],
   [26811, ('ivan.ivanov@test.ru','[First value, Second value]', '0', '0', '', '', '')]]

my_dict = {}
for i in range(len(literal_eval)):
    my_dict[literal_eval[i][0]] = literal_eval[i][1:]

for k,v in my_dict.items():
    print(k, '-', v)
```

```
26810 - [('vasya.vasin@test.ru', '[First value, Second value]', '0', '0', '', '', '')]
26811 - [('ivan.ivanov@test.ru', '[First value, Second value]', '0', '0', '', '', '')]
```

Answer (score 1):

еще вариант, на pandas, правда без цикла:

```
import pandas as pd

first_list = [[26810,"vasya.vasin@test.ru","[""First value"",""Second value""]","0","0","","",""], 
              [26811,"vasya2.vasin2@test.ru","[""First value"",""Second value""]","0","0","","",""]]

df = pd.DataFrame(first_list).set_index(0)
first_dict = df.apply(lambda x:tuple(x),axis=1).to_dict()

print(first_dict)
```

вывод:

```
{26810: ('vasya.vasin@test.ru', '[First value,Second value]', '0', '0', '', '', ''),
 26811: ('vasya2.vasin2@test.ru', '[First value,Second value]', '0', '0', '', '', '')}
```